# Customized formatting for picture captions

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a simple problem in MS word.

I need to write a report with a specific styling to the captions. The caption should be formatted like this

<Figure 2. Example Image>

But if I manually add the "<" in the caption, the "<" appears in the paragraph body when I cross reference Figure 2.

[Here is a brief example of the problem.](https://imgur.com/a/gxNmR1l)
Figure 1 is the normal styling, and Figure 2 has the pointy brackets around it.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: If you type `\<figure\>` the formatter will leave your brackets alone. I don't want to edit it myself because I don't want to break your intent as to which quote marks should & shouldn't be there.

Comment: @Tetsujin Ah thank you, I edited it so it reads better